# Defeat the draggable map feature after mousedown

Tags: google-maps-api-3, draggable

[Employing a variation on `function attachSecretMessage`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=it#EventClosures) and using a `mousedown` event, I am able to include the marker's `title` property as a Closure, but on the desktop platform, when a user clicks on the marker and then moves the mouse out of the opened `infowindow`, the map is dragged until the user clicks somewhere else (I don't know yet what happens on the mobile platform). I have attempted to remove the `draggable` feature of the map, but unsuccessfully. Can the draggability of the map be defeated?

```
function attachClickMessage(marker, message) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { content: message, size: new google.maps.Size(50,50) });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
        map.draggable = false;
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. It appears that simply resequencing the javascript instructions defeats the drag. I moved the `map.draggable = false;` after the `info window.open()` and no more dragging.

```
function attachClickMessage(marker, message) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { content: message, size: new google.maps.Size(50,50) });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        map.draggable = false;
        });
}
```